# Error making schunk_robots package - ivcon:command not found

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, schunk

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am attempting to make a package called schunk_robots.  However, I get the following error:

```
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
  -- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found version "2.7.3")
  [rosbuild] Building package schunk_description
  [rosbuild] Cached build flags older than manifests; calling rospack to get flags
  [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/fuerte/share/roscpp/rosbuild/roscpp.cmake
  [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/fuerte/share/rospy/rosbuild/rospy.cmake
  [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/fuerte/share/roslisp/rosbuild/roslisp.cmake
  -- Configuring done
  -- Generating done
  -- Build files have been written to: /home/karsh/powerball/controllerROS/allStuff/schunk_modular_robotics/schunk_description/build
  cd build && make -j4 -l4
  make[1]: Entering directory `/home/karsh/powerball/controllerROS/allStuff/schunk_modular_robotics/schunk_description/build'
  make[2]: Entering directory `/home/karsh/powerball/controllerROS/allStuff/schunk_modular_robotics/schunk_description/build'
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/karsh/powerball/controllerROS/allStuff/schunk_modular_robotics/schunk_description/build'
  Scanning dependencies of target media_files
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/karsh/powerball/controllerROS/allStuff/schunk_modular_robotics/schunk_description/build'
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/karsh/powerball/controllerROS/allStuff/schunk_modular_robotics/schunk_description/build'
  [  1%] [  2%] [  3%] Generating ../meshes/sdh/convex
  Generating ../meshes/sdh/iv
  [  4%] Generating ../meshes/powerball/convex
  [  5%] Generating ../meshes/powerball/iv
  Generating ../meshes/lwa/convex
  [  6%] Generating ../meshes/lwa/iv
  [  6%] [  7%] [  8%] Generating ../meshes/sdh/iv/finger_tip.iv
  Generating ../meshes/sdh/convex/finger_tip.obj
  make[3]: ivcon: Command not found
  make[3]: *** [../meshes/sdh/iv/finger_tip.iv] Error 127
  make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
  Generating ../meshes/sdh/convex/finger.obj
  make[3]: ivcon: Command not found
  make[3]: ivcon: Command not found
  make[3]: *** [../meshes/sdh/convex/finger_tip.obj] Error 127
  make[3]: *** [../meshes/sdh/convex/finger.obj] Error 127
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/karsh/powerball/controllerROS/allStuff/schunk_modular_robotics/schunk_description/build'
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/media_files.dir/all] Error 2
  make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/karsh/powerball/controllerROS/allStuff/schunk_modular_robotics/schunk_description/build'
  make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
  make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/karsh/powerball/controllerROS/allStuff/schunk_modular_robotics/schunk_description/build'
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
```

Does anyone know what this ivcon command is and why it's missing?  Thanks a lot for your help!

PS: I am using ROS Fuerte on Ubuntu 12.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65216/error-making-schunk_robots-package---ivcon:command-not-found/) by [sinha.karsh](https://answers.ros.org/users/3409/sinha.karsh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2013-06-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can install `ivcon` for fuerte from here http://www.ros.org/browse/details.php?distro=fuerte&name=ivcon

---

Originally posted by [makokal](https://answers.ros.org/users/31/makokal/) with karma: 1295 on 2013-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1